# Creating multiple instances on multiple button clicks

Tags: c#, wpf, class

Let's say I have a class, Person. I also have a button in a WPF window. I want to be able to click that button create a new Person instance (and then add it to a List).
What I don't get is how I do that. My understanding is that I need to specify an instance name (like `Person person1 = new Person()` - I need to specify that "personsomething" for each instance.

What if I wanted to have a school system with hundreds of people? I can't figure out a way to just click a button and create a new instance for each click (perhaps with some names and stuff, but that's besides the point).

I've got this

```
private void btnCreatePerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = new Person(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
        personList.Add(person);
        ClearTextBoxes();
    }
```

but that only works for a single instance of the class.

I do have to specify a name for each instance, right...?

Comment: you don't have to specify a variable name for each instance (its out of scope after this method anyway) but if this is your only constructor, then you do need to specify a persons name, you may want to create a default constructor but then you may end up down the line with some erroneous users (users without a valid name)

Comment: As said by @Sayse you don't need variable names for each instance. Because when later in your code you need to go through the list to perform some action, you can just run a foreach loop or do a First/FirstOrDefault/Where etc. as you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do have to specify a name for each instance, right...?

No. By adding the created instance to a list, you're creating one instance per person.

You can read them back from the list by iterating (`foreach (var person in personList) { ... }`) or querying them (`var person = personList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FirstName = "Joe")`).

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! Seems I need to read up on some stuff...
Thank you!